# alternatives 150w power supply 30 inch apple monitor

Tags: mac, display, high-definition

Seems like an obvious question but is there any of type of power supply that will work with the 30" mac monitors other than the 150w supply created by apple?

They have stopped producing these and its a big problem as mine has broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a long time searching i have finally found the alternative... but its not cheaper :p

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/FAN-COOLED-adapter-A1097-90w-A1098-150w-30-A1083-2-A1082-apple-cinema-display-/320935158781?pt=US_Monitor_Replacement_Parts&hash=item4ab939e3fd

Answer (score 0):

maybe you do not need a new power supply for that. From the distance, chances are good that only a few components inside the supply have gone weak. They could easily be repaired by a person with solid electronics background (high voltages).

I've done this a lot of times. Last one was time capsule. Again power supply. This happens frequently in hot and sparely ventilated environments like Apples enclosures.

Comment: :) cheers for the reply, but i actually don't have one at all. I lost it :(